# representation of rational field

Tags: irrational-numbers, extension-field, rational-numbers

I want to  know how is represented general form of rational field, for example definition of

${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is represented as $p+q \sqrt{2}$, where $p$ and  $q$ are rational numbers, for example let us consider following case

${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ is represented by

$$q_1 + q_2\sqrt{2} + q_3\sqrt{3} + q_4\sqrt{6}$$

My question is  in general how it is represented

${\mathbb Q}(q_1,q_2,q_3,...q_n)$  where  $q_1$ can be  rational or irrational number, thanks in advance

Comment: I think you have already represent the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a two dimensional vector space on field $\mathbb{Q}$ with basis $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$.

Comment: if we have for example $Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{4})$  ?

Comment: Then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$. $\{1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{4}\}$ is not a basis. $\sqrt{4} = 2 = 2 \cdot 1$

Comment: no no  maybe you did not understand my question,how is represented general form of $Q$ field?

Comment: It's not quite clear what kind of an answer you are looking for. In general we can say that the elements of $\Bbb{Q}(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ are all the numbers of the form $P(q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n)/R(q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n)$, where $P$ and $R$ are polynomials in $n$ variables with rational (integer) coefficients such that $R(q_1,\ldots,q_n)\neq0$. There will be repetitions in the sense that several pairs of polynomials may give the same number.

Comment: you mean that  it must satisfy $M(x+y)=M(x)+M(y)$ and $M(x*y)=M(x)*M(y)$?

Comment: could you post  as a answer?

Comment: What is $M$ there? Another way of looking at it is that $\Bbb{Q}(q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n)$ has to be a field (a subfield of the complex numbers), so it has to be closed under addition, multiplication, subtraction, division by non-zero elements, and it has to contain all the rational numbers as well all the $q_i$:s. It being closed under addition forces the linear combinations in there. Closed under multiplication forces all the polynomials in there, closed under division forces the P/R in.

Comment: (cont'd) For some specific numbers (like $\sqrt2$) we can stop sooner, because $\sqrt2^2=2$ so there is no need to go higher than quadratic polynomials, and division will come as a by-product (look up algebraic numbers to understand the reason). For some others (like $q_1=\pi$, look up transcendental numbers) we need all those rational functions.

Comment: M is automorphism transformation function

Comment: See [this quick overview](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExtensionField.html). You really should read a book on this to gain an understanding. IMHO the question is close to being too broad to be answered usefully here. I did upvote Callus' answer for the effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is much more complicated than you might think, which is either going to be bad news for you ( if you wanted to understand how field extensions work in five minutes ), or really good news for you ( if you were looking for a seriously rich and interesting avenue of study ).

Very very brief version:

1) if any of the $q_i$ are rational, you can ignore them.  They don't matter. if $q_1$ is rational, then $\mathbb{Q}(q_1,q_2)=\mathbb{Q}(q_2)$

2) The next important distinction is whether or not the $q_i$ are algebraic, ie., if they each satisfy a ( potentially different ) polynomial which coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.  If they all do, then you can say that every element of your field can be written as a linear combination of products of the generators.  Even more, if $q_i$ satisfies a polynomial of degree $n_i$, then the elements of your field can be written as linear combinations of $q_1^{m_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot q_r^{m_r}$ with $m_i \leq n_i$.  This is the case for $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3} )$ in your example.  The expressions are unlikely to be unique, though (although they are in the case of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ ).

3) If some of the $q_i$ are transcendental.... well, then you're pretty much stuck with Jyrki's comment that the elements of the field are rational functions of the generators.